# How to sort a NSMutableArray with custom object?

Tags: nsmutablearray, sorting

i have a mutable array with objects "XX" and i want to sort the array according to the variables contained in the object "XX" (see below the structure of the object).

I want to sort the array ascending by VALUE1,VALUE2 and then by NAME.

Is there any way to do it?

```
@interface XX:NSObject{

float VALUE1;
float VALUE2
NSString* NAME;

}

@end interface
```

Any help , very much appreciated!!! :-)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to use is something called a [Comparator block](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSComparator). This can be used to sort your array when you do

```
array sortUsingComparator: ^(id objA, id obj2){
   if(((XX*)objA).Value1 > ((XX*)obj2).Value1){
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
   }else if(((XX*)objA).Value1 < ((XX*)obj2).Value1){
        return (NSComparisionResult)NSOrderedAscending;
   }else{
      //keep comparing here, because value 1 are equal
   }
   //sorting logic goes here, returning a (NSComparisonResult) type here
}];
```